# Does IE10 Metro support userscripts?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10, userscripts

With Windows 7, I used google chrome and installed a bunch of userscripts to enhance my youtube experience (replay button, download options, etc).

Now that I have Windows 8, I want to get the same enhancements on IE10 metro. I understand that you can't use "addons", but is there a way to get userscripts to work?

Comment: @Adams> As a Greasemonkey author, I do. Would be great if we can finally reach 90%+ of all people with our scripts... (Opera + Chrome + Firefox is *only* around 70% I believe)

Comment: @BrockAdams: I do, hence why I asked. I actually really like the new IE10 enough for me to stop using Google Chrome (except for web development testing).

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking you might be able to use bookmarklets to inject a user-script by clicking, but I just looked and don't even see a way to stash bookmarklets on IE10 Metro. So I'm not very hopeful that there are any good solutions to your scenario.

I don't know if it's any consolation, but I believe IE10 works in Desktop Mode even on Windows RT devices such as the current Surface.